# Wireless Logitech Mouse

Tags: rss

I have a wireless Logitech mouse. The red light is on but the mouse no longer works. I have changed the battery. Same problem. I have had it for about 4 years. There is no reset button.  I do not know any additional information. However, the lid where the battery goes has the following info: SZ8  400-002123. Do I need to purchase a new mouse?  Help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried moving the receiver to a different USB slot? Have you tried using it on a different computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would unplug and re-plug in the USB toggle that is associated with the mouse. In another port if possible, as this will confirm the computer is recognizing the USB receiver.

If you do this and still have issues, then try the USB on another computer. Still have issues, then replace the device. You can get them really cheap, so then it comes to how much time you want to invest before replacing the unit.